# Parse-Dashboard: Server Not Reachable: unable to connect server Error

Tags: docker, parse-server, pm2, synology, parse-dashboard

I have [parse-server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) and [parse-dashboard](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard) installed with [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) in docker container in my synology nas as below:

```
+------+                                                         +-------------+
|      +NIC1 (192.168.1.100) <--> Router <--> (192.168.1.2) NIC1 +             |
|  PC  |                                                         |     DSM     |
|      +NIC2 (10.10.0.100) <--Peer-2-Peer---> (10.10.0.2)   NIC2 +             |
+------+                                                         |   [DOCKER]  |
                                                                 |(172.17.0.2) |
                                                                 +-------------+
```

for reference: for pm2 setup, i'm following: [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-3-%E2%80%93-install-and-configure-parse-server-and-pm2)

here is my parse-server and parse-dashboard pm2 ecosystem (defined in pm2's ecosystem.json):

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "parse-wrapper",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-server",
    "watch"       : true,
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/home/parse",
    "args"        : "--serverURL http://localhost:1337/parse",
    "env": {
      "PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD_CODE_MAIN": "/home/parse/cloud/main.js",
      "PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI": "mongodb://localhost/test",
      "PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID": "aeb932b93a9125c19df2fcaf3fd69fcb",
      "PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY": "358898112f354f8db593ea004ee88fed",
    }
  },{
    "name"        : "parse-dashboard-wrapper",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-dashboard",
    "watch"       : true,
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/home/parse/parse-dashboard",
    "args"        : "--config /home/parse/parse-dashboard/config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1"
  }]
}
```

here is my parse-dashboard config: */home/parse/parse-dashboard/config.json*

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "serverURL": "http://172.17.0.2:1337/parse",
    "appId": "aeb932b93a9125c19df2fcaf3fd69fcb",
    "masterKey": "358898112f354f8db593ea004ee88fed",
    "appName": "Parse Server",
    "iconName": "",
    "primaryBackgroundColor": "",
    "secondaryBackgroundColor": ""
  }],
  "users": [{
    "user": "user",
    "pass": "1234"
  }],
  "iconsFolder": "icons"
}
```

once you run: pm2 start ecosystem.json

here is parse-server log: `pm2 logs 0`

```
masterKey: ***REDACTED***
serverURL: http://localhost:1337/parse
masterKeyIps: []
logsFolder: ./logs
databaseURI: mongodb://localhost/test
userSensitiveFields: ["email"]
enableAnonymousUsers: true
allowClientClassCreation: true
maxUploadSize: 20mb
customPages: {}
sessionLength: 31536000
expireInactiveSessions: true
revokeSessionOnPasswordReset: true
schemaCacheTTL: 5000
cacheTTL: 5000
cacheMaxSize: 10000
objectIdSize: 10
port: 1337
host: 0.0.0.0
mountPath: /parse
scheduledPush: false
collectionPrefix:
verifyUserEmails: false
preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: false
enableSingleSchemaCache: false
jsonLogs: false
verbose: false
level: undefined

[1269] parse-server running on http://localhost:1337/parse
```

here is parse-dashboard log: `pm2 logs 1`

```
The dashboard is now available at http://0.0.0.0:4040/
```

once it's run, i can access 192.168.1.2:1337/parse (which will return `{"error":"unauthorized"}`)

and i can access 192.168.1.2:4040

but it return:

> Server not reachable: unable to connect to server

i see a lot of this issue can be solve by changing parse-dashboard config `"serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse"` to `"serverURL": "http://172.17.0.2:1337/parse"`

but to me, it's still no luck...

any idea what i've been missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so apparently, my */home/parse/parse-dashboard/config.json*:

```
"serverURL": "http://172.17.0.2:1337/parse"
```

should point to my DSM machine which is:

```
"serverURL": "http://192.168.1.2:1337/parse"
```